# Use js variable in php on same page js using ajax post type

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have one PHP file name as report.php in which I also created one script for id using post type which I have one post type of ajax for pass id.
    I want to use that post type id in my report.php query to comparing id.
    so how can I get that post id in my $str query to compare?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#project').on('click',function(){
        var pID = $(this).val();
        alert(pID);
        if(pID){
          $("#developer").show();
          $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'report1.php',
          data:'id='+pID,
          success:function(html){
            $('#developer').html(html);
          }
          }); 
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

In Below query, I want to compare post type id with given value.

```
$str = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT((u.firstname),' ',(u.lastname))) as dname, p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.hours)as spent_hrs, SUM(t.hours) as tot_spent,t.spent_on FROM time_entries as t 
    INNER Join projects as p on p.id = t.project_id 
    INNER Join users as u on u.id = t.user_id 
    where p.id=$_POST[id] and u.id=6 
    GROUP By p.id,t.spent_on ";
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can batter idea see this answer further query you can ask a community 
[jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

```
$('#devloper').on('click',function(){
        var dID = $(this).val();


      });
```

Comment: You did not have any idea regarding my issue?

Comment: this populated first dropdown and then you can  selected value from second  the dropdown

Comment: Sorry but I think you did not understand my issue.

Answer (score 1):

change your ajax request data:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'report1.php',
    data:'id:'+pID,
    success:function(html_data){
      $('#developer').html(html_data);
    }
});
```

then in **report1.php** page you can get id using `$_POST['id'];`

Comment: where I have to put this "get id using $_POST['id'];" ?

Comment: which issue are you getting?

Comment: Thank You for your feedback @B.Desai

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#developer').on('click',function(){
        var dID = $(this).val();
        if(dID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'report1.php',
                data: 'pid='+pID+'did='+dID,
                success:function(html_data){
                    // console.log(html);
                  $('#developer').html(html_data);
                 }  
            }); 
        }
    });
```